# How to save resulted values from firestore into a variable and use it on various components and states in Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for a way to save the results received from a firestore collection and use it on a variable and reuse the save it to data() and reuse it.

I'm unsure how to save the results from a async function into a variable.

Please help me with this guys

Here is my code.

```
    import firebase from "firebase";


export default{

  data() {
    return {
      uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      teamLead: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    db.collection("users").onSnapshot(users => {
      users.docChanges().forEach(user => {
        if (this.uid == user.doc.id) {
          this.teamLead = user.doc.data().teamLead
        }
      });
    });

  console.log(this.teamLead)
```

**In this code** I would like to have the value of teamLead saved into the data() function. How do I do that?

Comment: Any suggestion guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a crazy idea to read all user from db. Instead of you can retrieve user by id.
2. Don't use "this" inside callbacks or lambda.
3. You have to understand order of execution of async programs. See my comments.

[]

```
export default{
      data() {
        return {     
          teamLead: ""
        };
      },
      created() {
        let self = this  
        db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              self.teamLead = doc.data().teamLead
              console.log(self.teamLead)//<-- this log will executed after firestore return any data
            }        
        });

      console.log(this.teamLead)//<-- this log will executed before firestore return any data
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add an explenation about how/why this piece of code answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Valera. However my problem still persists. I would like to use the data collected into teamLead variable after completion of firestore. Since I need to collect data again based on the result that I receive. Please let me post my database schema.

Comment: I am working with firestore and have been struggling with the database structure. I have a collection called** "Users"** and inside that I have several documents holding users data like his name, lead, and so on. I have also have another collection, in the name "contact" inside this, I have some documents "Some name" example leads name inside it. And inside the leads name document, I've multiple collections based on the date and inside the date have those contacts. @AndréKool

Comment: In this case, I would like to retrieve the lead name from the users collection and would like to search through the contacts collection for those contact saved under this leads name. Hope I'm clear. Any suggestions on how I can structure my data.  @Valera Kvip